# There has been an error processing your request error

Tags: error, dashboard

I have installed the OwlCarouselSlider for Magento 2 downloaded from the MarketPlace. Upon login to the dashboard i get the following error:

**There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
Error log record number: 2019932515**

This is a copy of the report.

```
a:4:{i:0;s:71:"Setup version for module 'WeltPixel_OwlCarouselSlider' is not specified";i:1;s:1383:"#0 D:\xampp\htdocs\PCM\store\vendor\magento\framework\Module\DbVersionInfo.php(56): Magento\Framework\Module\DbVersionInfo->isModuleVersionEqual('WeltPixel_OwlCa...', '1.0.1')
#1 D:\xampp\htdocs\PCM\store\vendor\magento\framework\Module\DbVersionInfo.php(79): Magento\Framework\Module\DbVersionInfo->isSchemaUpToDate('WeltPixel_OwlCa...')
#2 D:\xampp\htdocs\PCM\store\vendor\magento\framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator.php(55): Magento\Framework\Module\DbVersionInfo->getDbVersionErrors()
#3 D:\xampp\htdocs\PCM\store\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#4 D:\xampp\htdocs\PCM\store\var\generation\Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#5 D:\xampp\htdocs\PCM\store\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#6 D:\xampp\htdocs\PCM\store\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#7 D:\xampp\htdocs\PCM\store\index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#8 {main}";s:3:"url";s:20:"/PCM/store/admin_pcm";s:11:"script_name";s:20:"/PCM/store/index.php";}
```

I have also run the following commands:

```
bin\magento indexer:reindex
bin\magento setup:static-content:deploy
bin\magento cache:flush
bin\magento module:enable WeltPixel_OwlCarouselSlider
bin\magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile -vvv
```

None of these worked. Any ideas on how to fix the issue or remove the extension completely from the store?

Thanks